# very unique exception for BlockingCollection on .net 4.0

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, producer-consumer

i'm using the `BlockingCollection` for a Producer Consumer pattern and i got an excecption i think to write a patent on it- only two results in google!
the expection is "CompleteAdding may not be used concurrently with additions to the collection" and it happens when i `TryAdd` on th BlockingCollection as Follows:

```
 public void EnqueueTask(T item)
    {
        if (!_cancellationTokenSource.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            _workerQueue.Add(item);
        }
    }
```

the `CompleteAdding` is called on the dispose of the Consumer-Producer wrapper class:

```
  public void Dispose()
    {
        if (!_IsActive)
            return;
        _IsActive = false;
        _cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
        _workerQueue.CompleteAdding();
        // Wait for the consumer's thread to finish.
        for (int i = 0; i < _workers.Length; ++i)
        {
            Task t1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                try
                {
                    if (!_workers[i].Join(4000))
                        LogWriter.Trace("Failed to join thread", "ThreadFailureOnDispose");
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    OnLogged(ex.Message + ex.StackTrace);
                }
            });

        }


        // Release any OS resources.
    }
```

Anyone from microsoft got an idea? should i sleep after the cancelation and before calling the CompleteAdding?

Comment: What is the type of the exception? The documentation says that `Add` (and `TryAdd`) will throw `InvalidOperationException` if you try to add an item after `CompleteAdding` has been called. Your description isn't too clear, but if you're getting the exception on the `Add` call, I suspect that's it.

Answer (score 5):

Look at this piece of the code:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < _workers.Length; ++i)
    {
        Task t1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            try
            {
                if (!_workers[i].Join(4000))   << == Here
                    LogWriter.Trace("Failed to join thread", "ThreadFailureOnDispose");
            }
```

In `_workers[i].Join(4000)`, the value of `i` is not what you think it is. Try again with:

```
   for (int i = 0; i < _workers.Length; ++i)
    {
        int j = i;  // copy
        Task t1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            try
            {
                if (!_workers[j].Join(4000))  // j
                    LogWriter.Trace("Failed to join thread", "ThreadFailureOnDispose");
            }
```

In your version, the variable 'i' is captured and all Tasks use the same var. All but the first few will see `i == _workers.Length` because they are executed after the for-loop is completed.

It is a classic lambda + captured var problem.

Comment: Ah, the classic captured iteration variable. Good spot.

Comment: it's not realted to the question but if you mean the ++i instead of the i++ - it's a Typo.

Comment: @user - take a copy of i inside the foreach; refer only to that copy.

Comment: @user, no it is not about i++ but the use of i inside the lambda.